# Django function redirects back to class

Tags: python, django

I am trying to get it so anytime my function `delete_curricula_info` is activated it then redirects to `CurriculumClasses` url

```
class CurriculumClasses(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'architect/assignclasses.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = AssignClassForm(self.request.GET or None)
        context['classes'] = Classes.objects.all()
        context['curricula_infos'] = CurriculaInfo.objects.all()
        context['course_abbr'] = self.kwargs.get('course_abbr')
        context['year'] = self.kwargs.get('year')
        context['semester'] = self.kwargs.get('semester')
        context['module_abbr'] = self.kwargs.get('module_abbr')
        context['curricula'] = Curricula.objects.get(
            course_period__course__course_abbreviation=self.kwargs.get('course_abbr'),
            module_period__module__module_abbreviation=self.kwargs.get('module_abbr'),
            course_period__period__academic_year=self.kwargs.get('year'),
            course_period__period__semester=self.kwargs.get('semester')).pk

        return context

def delete_curricula_info(request, pk):
    curricula_info = get_object_or_404(CurriculaInfo, pk=pk)
    curricula_info.delete()

    return redirect('curriculum_classes')
```

Heres my urls.py

```
path('courses/<str:course_abbr>/<str:module_abbr>/<int:year>/<int:semester>/classes/',
         views.CurriculumClasses.as_view(), name='curriculum_classes'),
path('delete-curricula-info/<int:pk>/', views.delete_curricula_info, name='delete_curricula_info')
```

The url for my  `CurriculumClasses` is using a dynamic one so i could not hardcode the url to the return redirect of my function. So how do i redirect as my current method does not work. Thanks.

Comment: You should have posted the error rather than saying "does not work". But clearly the "curriculum_classes" view requires several parameters - course, module, year, semester. What values do you want to use for these when you redirect? Where will those values be coming from?

Comment: The function works however the return redirect line give the error "Reverse for 'curriculum_classes' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['courses\\/(?P<course_abbr>[^/]+)\\/(?P<module_abbr>[^/]+)\\/(?P<year>[0-9]+)\\/(?P<semester>[0-9]+)\\/classes\\/$']"

Comment: Yes, as I said you need values for all those parameters. Where will you get them?

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect it like this:

```
from django.urls import reverse

def delete_curricula_info(request, pk):
    curricula_info = get_object_or_404(CurriculaInfo, pk=pk)
    curricula_info.delete()

    course_abbr = 'xxx'
    module_abbr = 'xxx'
    year = 2018
    semester = 1
    args = (course_abbr, module_abbr, year, semester)
    return redirect(reverse('curriculum_classes', args=args))
```